# Return 401 Unauthorized with ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a modal form that has an anchor tag with an `ng-click="SignInAsDifferentUser()"` I want it to call my controller and immediately return a 401 unauthorized so that the windows authentication dialog opens, I initially wrote a nice modal with a nice form for authenticating as a different windows user but can't get it to work so I have created a new modal that display the currently logged on windows user with a link under it to sign in as a different user.The link works and I can use the debugger to step through the code but cant get it to return 401 on purpose.

I have done google searches but most everything I search comes back with example on how to get the windows user, I have that already, other searches show how to use interceptors, I don't need to intercept anything and I don't want to make a call to the server.

How do I purposely return 401 unauthorized on `ng-click`?

**JS:**

```
var auth = angular.module('Authentication', []);

auth.controller('WindowsAuthController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.SignInAsDifferentUser = function () {
        var response = { error: {"status":401, "statusText":"Better authenticate using windows"} };
        return response;
    }
}])
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="ChangeWindowsUserForm" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="WindowsAuthModalLabel" ng-controller="WindowsAuthController">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="WindowsAuthModalLabel">Windows Login</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="windowsauth_currentuser">Current User:</label>
                    <p id="windowsauth_currentuser" class=".form-control-static">@ViewBag.DomainUserName</p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <a href ng-click="SignInAsDifferentUser()">Sign in as different user.</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 401 is an HTTP status code ! what do you mean by *return 401 unauthorized* ?

Comment: exactly what i said, i want to mock the server response without calling the server, I want to say the call wasn't authorized to force the builtin windows login to open.

Comment: Okey ! we need to see how the built-in window works !

Comment: If you look at this link it shows how to signin as a different user like you would in sharepoint, it shows making a call to the server and the purposely returning 401 to make the windows dialog open: https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2009/12/01/asp-net-c-how-to-sign-in-as-different-user-like-in-microsoft-sharepoint-with-windows-authentication/ I want to do the same thing but didnt want to make the call to the server.

Comment: You can use events for that purpose !

Comment: I tried an event once and couldn't get it to work, can you show me how you would do it?

Comment: Please take a look at this https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec#.giggo9nfl !

Comment: I ended up going a completely different way: http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/08/how-to-force-sign-in-as-different-user.html -- I ripped out my angular and then just called the code shown in the link from my html, works perfectly now.